# onActivityResult error when I press "cancel" button on my second Activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult, cancel-button

I have the next activities:

**Activity1**

```
//declare
private static final int SAVE_DATA_FROM_ACTIVITY = 203;

//........... not important code

//button to open second Activity
public void btn_openSecondActivity(View view)
    {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);

            startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_DATA_FROM_ACTIVITY);
        }
    }


 protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      if (requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity)
        {
            name= data.getStringExtra("Name");
        }
    }


//....... not important code
```

**Activity2**

On Second Activity I have two buttons:

1. Cancel
2. Save

//............

```
//declare
private static final int OK_RESULT_CODE = 1;

//Cancel button
public void btn_cancel(View view)
{
    finish();
}

//Save button
public void btn_save (View view)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Name",et_name.getText().toString());

    setResult(OK_RESULT_CODE, intent);

    finish();
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I click Save button all works perfect, but the problem it's when I click Cancel button, then it's reports an error:

```
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=203, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.alvaro.project/com.alvaro.project.Activity1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**I understand the problem, when I cancel is not the same result code but i don't know how I can solve it**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issue in `onActivityResult` method. You don't check result.

Change your condition from :

```
if (requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity)
```

to:

```
if (resultCode  == OK_RESULT_CODE  && requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
if (requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity)
    {
        name= data.getStringExtra("Name");
    }
```

into

```
   if (requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        name= data.getStringExtra("Name");
    }
```

and

Your cancel method is like

```
public void btn_cancel(View view)
{
   setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
}
```

And instead of **OK_RESULT_CODE** use Android default ok like **Activity.RESULT_OK**

Answer (score 0):

Check if you manage to set the result

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  if (requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity && resultCode = Activity2.OK_RESULT_CODE)
    {
        name= data.getStringExtra("Name");
    } else {
       //probably btn_cancel pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your OK_RESULT_CODE is public

Answer (score 0):

check resultCode in onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      if (resultCode == 1/*OK_RESULT_CODE from Second Activity */ && requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity)
        {
            name= data.getStringExtra("Name");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Activity1**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SAVE_DATA_FROM_activity) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            name = data.getStringExtra("Name");
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            // TODO something
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity2**

delete field OK_RESULT_CODE

```
//Cancel button
public void btn_cancel(View view) {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
    finish();
}

//Save button
public void btn_save(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Name", et_name.getText().toString());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}
```